# Create and show items in the samve view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

While trying to build a form to create new items on an index page rather than the new view, i ran into a curious problem.

When presenting the form for creation of a new task in the current project, the @tasks variable that contains the tasks that are supposed to be displayed in the list below, seems to be empty. Therefore i get a "No route matches" since the object im passing to ie. complete_project_task_path is nil.

When removing the form, everything works like a charm. Any ideas why this happens?

```
<h1>Listing tasks</h1>

<%= form_for([@project, @project.tasks.build]) do |f| %>
    <div id="new_quick_task">
        <%= f.text_field :title, :value => 'Quickly add a new task' %>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>

<div id="task_list">
    <% @tasks.each do |task| %>

        <div class="task">
            <div class="completed"><%= task.completed %></div>
            <div class="complete_link"><%= link_to "Good", complete_project_task_path(@project, task) %></div>
            <div class="title"><%= link_to task.title, project_task_path(@project, task) %></div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div> <!-- end task_list -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use `@tasks` and not `@project.tasks`? because it would show the new task you created for your form?.

Well, you could still use `@project.tasks` and do something like:

```
<% @project.tasks.each do |task| %>
  <% unless task.title.nil? %>
    <div class="task">
        <div class="completed"><%= task.completed %></div>
        <div class="complete_link"><%= link_to "Good", complete_project_task_path(@project, task) %></div>
        <div class="title"><%= link_to task.title, project_task_path(@project, task) %></div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

which would skip the tasks without the title.

The error you get is not because the `@tasks` variable is empty, because if it was, you would never come to the code below it. The error you get is that one of the items inside your `@tasks` contains a value it does not expect. I guess it has something to do with your `complete_project_task_path(@project, task)` that will check something of `task` that is not set correctly?

Answer (score 0):

So i think i figured it out. (please correct me if im wrong)

> Ruby variables hold references to
>   objects and the = operator copies the
>   references.

(from http://ruby-doc.org/docs/Newcomers/ruby.html#objects no. 17)

Taking that into account, look at the following example

```
@task_list = @project.tasks
```

This essentially makes `@task_list` refer to the same object as `@project.tasks`. If the data in `@project.tasks` changes, so does `@task_list's` data because they both point to the same object.

`@project.tasks.build` seems to alter the object, that both `@project.taks` and `@task_list` point to, in some way.

The solution was pretty simple. Instead of setting @task_list = @project.tasks i created a new object for @task_list.

So in the controller, istead of doing this:

```
@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
@task_list = @project.tasks
```

just do it like this:

```
@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
@taks_list = Task.where(:project_id => @project.id)
```

Comment: While this would work, you are copying/re-implementing the association code you already have. The solution i offered will ignore the new object in the list and normally does exactly what you want.